# How can we edit the SVG format file and save as .html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this SVG code which I am trying to use in html 5, but i it's not running, how to use this SVG code in html 5? The code is fully running when the file is saved in SVG format. But how this code can be saved in html 5 form?

```
<svg    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <script><![CDATA[
        var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        Root=document.documentElement
        standardize(Root)

        function standardize(R){
            var Attr={
                "onmouseup":"add(evt)",
                "onmousedown":"grab(evt)",
                "onmousemove":null,
                "onmouseover":"hilight(evt)",
                "onmouseout":"hilight(evt)"
            }
            assignAttr(R,Attr)
        }
        function hilight(evt){
            var T=evt.target
            if (T.nodeName=="rect") return
            if (evt.type=="mouseover") T.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-opacity",1)
            else T.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-opacity",.5)
        }
        function add(evt){
            if (evt.target.nodeName!="rect") return
            var C=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle") 
            var stroke=Color()
            var rad=10+Math.random()*50
            var Attr={
                r:rad,
                cx:evt.clientX,
                cy:evt.clientY,
                "fill": Color(),
                "fill-opacity":.75,
                "stroke": stroke,
                "stroke-opacity":.5,
                "id":stroke,
                "stroke-width":10+Math.random()*(55-rad)
            }
            assignAttr(C,Attr)
            Root.appendChild(C)
        }
        function grab(evt){
            var O=evt.target
            if (evt.target.nodeName=="rect") return
            var Attr={
                "onmousemove":"slide(evt,'"+O.id+"')",
                "onmouseup":"standardize(Root)"
            }
            assignAttr(Root,Attr)
        }
        function slide(evt,id){
            var o=document.getElementById(id)
            var c=""; if (o.nodeName=="circle") c="c"
            o.setAttributeNS(null, c+"x", evt.clientX)
            o.setAttributeNS(null, c+"y", evt.clientY)
        }
        function assignAttr(O,A){
            for (i in A) O.setAttributeNS(null,i, A[i])
        }
        function Color(){
            return "rgb("+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+")"
        }
    ]]>
    </script>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
    <text font-size="12pt" x="50" y="20" id="t1">Click something to move it</text>
    <text font-size="12pt" x="80" y="40" id="t2">Click nothing to add something</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: SVG is a native element in HTML5, so just take the script out of the SVG, and put it in its own element next to the SVG element, using normal HTML5 rules for what scripts should look like.

Comment: can u please elaborate ? i tried that but the code is not working ? can u please edit the above code in html and send it to me ?

Comment: no, but if you make a jsfiddle.net example of what you have, I (and others) can edit that and then post a link to a reworked copy.

Comment: sorry iam new to this place ? i visited jsfiddle.net site, but it has css html and javascript so how can i make .net from my SVG file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's because in your javascript the root element get changed if you save in html file.

Just to test it, you can type `document.documentElement` on browser console, then if you save file as SVG the root element refers to SVG element whereas if you save it as html then it refers to HTML element.

So the solution is add a **id** to SVG element and access SVG element through id. Here is the updated working code.

```
<html>
<body>

<svg    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svgbeast" >

    <script><![CDATA[
        var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        Root=document.getElementById("svgbeast")
        standardize(Root)

        function standardize(R){
            var Attr={
                "onmouseup":"add(evt)",
                "onmousedown":"grab(evt)",
                "onmousemove":null,
                "onmouseover":"hilight(evt)",
                "onmouseout":"hilight(evt)"
            }
            assignAttr(R,Attr)
        }
        function hilight(evt){
            var T=evt.target
            if (T.nodeName=="rect") return
            if (evt.type=="mouseover") T.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-opacity",1)
            else T.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-opacity",.5)
        }
        function add(evt){
            if (evt.target.nodeName!="rect") return
            var C=document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle") 
            var stroke=Color()
            var rad=10+Math.random()*50
            var Attr={
                r:rad,
                cx:evt.clientX,
                cy:evt.clientY,
                "fill": Color(),
                "fill-opacity":.75,
                "stroke": stroke,
                "stroke-opacity":.5,
                "id":stroke,
                "stroke-width":10+Math.random()*(55-rad)
            }
            assignAttr(C,Attr)
            Root.appendChild(C)
        }
        function grab(evt){
            var O=evt.target
            if (evt.target.nodeName=="rect") return
            var Attr={
                "onmousemove":"slide(evt,'"+O.id+"')",
                "onmouseup":"standardize(Root)"
            }
            assignAttr(Root,Attr)
        }
        function slide(evt,id){
            var o=document.getElementById(id)
            var c=""; if (o.nodeName=="circle") c="c"
            o.setAttributeNS(null, c+"x", evt.clientX)
            o.setAttributeNS(null, c+"y", evt.clientY)
        }
        function assignAttr(O,A){
            for (i in A) O.setAttributeNS(null,i, A[i])
        }
        function Color(){
            return "rgb("+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+")"
        }
    ]]>
    </script>

    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
    <text font-size="12pt" x="50" y="20" id="t1">Click something to move it</text>
    <text font-size="12pt" x="80" y="40" id="t2">Click nothing to add something</text>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to edit an SVG formatted file. Most modern browsers can render SVG, and treat SVG like any other HTML tag.

To make this work however, you need to place your code inside valid html, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- code goes here !-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Save as HTML and view your file.

Also if you want to verify, change this line from:

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
```

to:

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
```

And you'll see red, so SVG is rendering properly.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LX7vy/) (note that JSFiddle automatically surrounds your HTML code with proper HTML).

As an side, the javascript contains an error inside the mouse events (onmousemove, onmouseclick, etc).

Comment: Ah, I wasn't clear. I updated the answer. You put the entire code inside the body tag, javascript and all.

Comment: Yes i did that, SVG is also working, but the javascript in it is not working ? that's the problem. How can i enter the javascript in SVG ?